# Creating only one class object from many classes depending on user input in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a program in which I have 5 brands and one class for each brand. I want to create only  instance of that class which user wants to know about. No object should be created other than the brand which is the input from user. I used switch statement but this did not work. Is there any better way to do that?
How should it be done so that that particular object remains throughout the main scope.
Here is my code.

```
    string brandInput= brand.brandNameEvaluator();
   // above is method which is getting input of brand name from user.
       switch (brandInput)
       {
           case "Suzuki":
               Suzuki suzuki = new Suzuki();
               break;
           case "Honda":
               Honda honda = new Honda();
               break;
           case "Ferrari":
               Ferrari ferrari = new Ferrari();
               break;
           case "Toyota":
               Toyota toyota = new Toyota();
               break;
           case "BMW":
               BMW bmw = new BMW();
               break;

           default:
               Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.. We are sorry for the  inconvenience");
               break;
       }
```

Comment: take a look at Factory desighn pathern (for example here) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

or use the same interface to all of those classes and store selected project as interface (if it fits your project needs)

Comment: @Misiakw, Good suggestion in general, but I think the Factory pattern is overkill for this situation, and likely too complex for OP to implement based on OP's question... interface or better yet, an abstract class, might be a better option.

Comment: it depends on project size. also keep in mind that the project may get bigger and bigger. it's better to spend some more time to save even more time later (and to get used to good practices) than to make some "nasty but working" solutions.

Comment: @mac, you can't use `this` pointer in a `static` method - there is no `this`, by definition... Take a look at MSDN reference for `this` keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a base class for what a car is and have the different types inherit from it

```
public abstract class Car
{
    //Properties
}

public class Suzuki : Car {}
```

And then in your code:

```
Car car = null;
string brandInput= brand.brandNameEvaluator();

switch (brandInput)
{
   case "Suzuki":
       car = new Suzuki();
       break;
   case "Honda":
       car = new Honda();
       break;
   case "Ferrari":
       car = new Ferrari();
       break;
   case "Toyota":
       car = new Toyota();
       break;
   case "BMW":
       car = new BMW();
       break;
}

if (car == null)
{
    //Do something and exit
}
```

In addition, I'd recommend using the [Factory design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) for the creation of the cars.

Comment: Would `var car;` actually work without initialization? Maybe you meant `var car = new Car();`

Comment: @uteist - Corrected. But not to initialize a `Car` because it is an abstract class

Comment: Ah, thought it was just a base class but it is better to use abstract indeed.

Comment: @mac - Great :)

Comment: @utiest surely, just some tests i need to make. if goes all fine surely i will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

The 5 classes should inherit from an abstract base class, which allows you to create that datatype. The switch approach would still work. Example:

```
   BaseCar car;
   string brandInput= brand.brandNameEvaluator();

   switch (brandInput)
   {
       case "Suzuki":
           car = new Suzuki();
           break;
       case "Honda":
           car = new Honda();
           break;
       case "Ferrari":
           car = new Ferrari();
           break;
       case "Toyota":
           car = new Toyota();
           break;
       case "BMW":
           car = new BMW();
           break;

       default:
           Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.. We are sorry for the  inconvenience");
           break;
   }
```